# Building libFLAC 1.3.2 for iOS

Tags: ios, compilation, configure, flac

I'd like to integrate FLAC support in an iOS audio app so I need to build libFLAC 1.3.2 for iOS targets, and I've been stuck on that for a while.

I tried to adapt [Chris Ballinger's libOpus building script](https://github.com/chrisballinger/Opus-iOS/blob/master/build-libopus.sh).

I managed to take care of the dependency on libogg by downloading and extracting libogg 1.3.3 and adding --with-ogg=${LIBOGGDIR} option to the configure call.

All 5 compilations run smoothly, but when it comes to the lipo part, I get the following error (I simpliflied the paths with [...] for readibility) :

```
lipo: [...]/iPhoneOS11.2-armv7.sdk/lib/libFLAC.a and [...]/iPhoneOS11.2-armv7s.sdk/lib/libFLAC.a have the same architectures (x86_64) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

I tried the lipo command with several couples of built architectures, I get the same error every time: same architectures (x86_64).

If this can be of any information, I get the following output at the end of configure with armv7, armv7s or arm64 :

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Configuration Complete =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

  Configuration summary :

    FLAC version : ........................ 1.3.2

    Host CPU : ............................ arm
    Host Vendor : ......................... apple
    Host OS : ............................. darwin

    Compiler is GCC : ..................... no
    Compiler is Clang : ................... yes
    SSE optimizations : ................... yes
    Asm optimizations : ................... no
    Ogg/FLAC support : .................... yes
```

Any idea of how to get libFLAC built for iOS targets armv7, armv7s and arm64 ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm trying to compile the same, but for tvOS, but steps should be similar.

Comment: BTW maybe you can try  to disable SSE? `--disable-sse` I think that's only for x86 CPUs and that would only be "useful" when running in Simulator if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/jhurt/FLACiOS

I'm not exactly familiar with the whole build process but that repository does just what we're looking for.

It had a build error when using current Xcode (10), I fixed that in a pull request. https://github.com/jhurt/FLACiOS/pull/8

I got it to build for tvOS also.